# MYSQL user privileges keep resetting

Tags: mysql

encountered this issue mentioned in title and wonder if anyone has encountered this before or have a remedy for it.

Steps I've taken:

1. Login to db as "root" user
2. Create a "readonly" user
3. Server Privileges: only "Select" is checked
4. Privileges: only "extraction" (this is a stored procedure)  is
   inserted
5. After creation I've double verified by using this "readonly" user to
   run/execute the "Extraction" function and it works.

Issue: After a few days, using the same login "readonly" user produces this error "1370 - execute command denied to user 'readonly'@'localhost' for routine '.extraction'"

Interim solution: is to always run this query "grant execute on procedure
.`extraction` to 'readonly'@'localhost' identified by '';" when the issue surfaces

What baffles me is why is this happening?

MYSQL Version: 5.0.95
Client Interface: Navicat Lite v10.0.5

Many thanks in advance

Comment: after the grants did you `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` ? also in the time after it worked and till it didn't was the mysql server restarted?

Comment: Hi Stephan, after the grants none of the following was done: 
"FLUSH PRIVILEGES", 
restart the mysql server

Do I execute both or either one?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you checked `mysql.user` table to see that the execute right is present ?

Comment: Yes every time i ran the query mentioned in the interim solution the privileges are correct for the user.

Comment: Try to `FULSH PRIVILEGES` and check the rights again because i suspect that the grant is not persisted and its just kept in memory ... you can read more here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html

Comment: also can you pls post the sql statements used for each step

Comment: I've added a "Flush PRIVILEGES;" will monitor if it still comes back.

This is what I ran "
grant execute on procedure
<dbname>.`extraction`
to 'readonly'@'localhost'
identified by '<password>';

Flush Privileges;
"

Thanks for your help

Comment: ok good, also from what host do you call the procedure using readonly user ? i assume localhost because from other hosts it will give you access denied

Comment: yes, i ran the queries thru localhost. really appreciate your help.

Comment: np, let me know if this fixed your problem